# How does one pass applicaton private files to android Service in a separate process

Tags: android, security, service

I am a bit of a noob at android but I have an application where one part of the application generates large data files which I want to schedule into a service running as a separate process (for robustness reasons) for upload to a remote server.  This process will handle complicated stuff like retrying and resuming upload if the device is rebooted etc.  When the upload is complete then it would delete the file.

The files can be large.

But I find even within the same application package where the context in both the separated process service and the application's other modules points to the same private "files" path when I try to open a file written by the application UI module in the separated process service, I get a permission denied error even though both modules are part of the same application package.

What is the best way to do this that does not involve passing all the data through IPC but instead simply opening and reading the file in the separate process uploader service after it is written.

I have looked at the content provider system a bit and it looks like what is needed but seems like overkill for passing files within modules of the same application package, and copying them is a waste of CPU and hence battery life.

Is there any way to give both processes access to a shared folder yet keep the folder private within the group of modules specified in the package?  Or is the ContentProvider system the only proper way to do this?  And does it avoid copying the data?

Comment: I don't think you should split the solution in two apps. You can use services to do that. Different PIDs to the same application. eg.: `betorcs@betorcs:~/Desktop/task/orig$ adb shell ps | grep pitanga
u0_a143   <b>12577</b> 110   584532 21920 ffffffff 00000000 S org.devmaster.pitanga
u0_a143   <b>12594</b> 110   577944 17508 ffffffff 00000000 S org.devmaster.pitanga:monitor`

Comment: Did you had a look at: http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Comment: what "copying" do you mean when using `ContentProvider` ?

Comment: What are you referring to when you talk about modules within a package? Implementing a content provider isnt a lot of work. Maybe you better use FileProvider. It can 'serve' complete directories too. Well a content privider can too.

Comment: I only have one app - but the app contains within it a "sevice" which runs as a separate process.  both the service and the other activites have the same "files" folder specified by thier context however a file written to the folder from an activity when attempted to be read or altered by the service process throws a permission exception.

As far as copying whether the file is simply altered in terms of it's permissions (group ownership) or copied to a clone in the other process behind the scenes.

I'll look at the FileProvider and see what that offers.

Comment: well I might rephrase the question - How do I assign a private file folder to a separated process Service - then the service can manage the files and be set up as a content provider.

Comment: How does one add a Service to an app so it runs as a separate process? What did you do for that? I have apps wil lots of activities and services and they have all the same access to the internal memory.

Comment: `How do I assign a private file folder to a separated process Service - then the service can manage the files and be set up as a content provider.`. No Wrongly rephrased. A separate process service can only handle the private files of an activity if that activity provides a content provider. Having said that i still do not understand the permission exception you described.

Comment: In the manifest file for the service:

       <service
                android:name=".xxxxxService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:isolatedProcess="true"

This defines the service as a "isolated process" meaning it has a separate heap etc and can't share memory objects with the application process.
t's context inherits from containing application definition in the manifest,   However the process has no access to files in the private area.

I need persistent storage.

How? Can? does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - getting further into android, It seems an "isolatedProcess" service has no permissions to access *anything* outside of IPC or lower level interprocess communications primitives.

BUT - if you specify a separate "android:process" name for the service but DO-NOT specify it as an "isolatedProcess" it *is* run in a "separate" process with the given name with it's own heap etc which also has the ability to access private storage.

So that is what I did and all works as desired.